# XML: How to get Elements by Attribute Value - Python 2.7 and minidom

Tags: python, xml, python-2.7, minidom

I want to get a list of XML Elements based **first** on TagName and **second** on Attribute Value. 
I´m using the xml.dom library and python 2.7.

While it´s easy to get the first step done:

```
from xml.dom import minidom
xmldoc = minidom.parse(r"C:\File.xml")
PFD = xmldoc.getElementsByTagName("PFD")
PNT = PFD.getElementsByTagName("PNT")
```

I´ve been looking around but cannot find a solution for the second step. Is there something like a `.getElementsByAttributeValue` that would give me a list to work with?

If the XML looks like this

```
<PFD>
     <PNT A="1" B=.../>
     <PNT A="1" B=.../>
     <PNT A="2" B=.../>
</PFD>
```

In need all PNTs where A="1" in a list.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you don't find a built-in method, why not iterate over the items?

```
from xml.dom import minidom
xmldoc = minidom.parse(r"C:\File.xml")
PFD = xmldoc.getElementsByTagName("PFD")
PNT = xmldoc.getElementsByTagName("PNT")
for element in PNT:
    if element.getAttribute('A') == "1":
        print "element found"
```

Adding the items to a list should be easy now.

Answer (score 7):

If you aren't limited to using xml.dom.minidom, [lxml](http://lxml.de/) has better search functionality.  Note that lxml is not builtin, and will require installing the [lxml package](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/lxml) and non-Python dependencies.

Eg:

```
>>> from lxml import etree
>>> root = etree.parse(r"C:\File.xml")
>>> for e in root.findall('PNT[@A="1"]'):
...     print etree.tostring(e)
<PNT A="1" B="c"/>
<PNT A="1" B="b"/>
```

Lxml also supports all of [XPath](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath) via `element.xpath('query')`.  Other convenience functions include `element.findtext` which finds the appropriate element and returns the text of it, `element.find` and `element.findall` which returns the first/list of all elements matching a query using a subset of XPath covering common queries.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
from xml.dom import minidom

xmldoc = minidom.parse(r"C:\File.xml")
PNT = xmldoc.getElementsByTagName("PNT")

for element in PNT:
    print element.attributes.keys()
    for elem in element.attributes.values():
        print elem.firstChild.data
```